# microservice authentication between services with basic auth

Tags: authentication, microservices

I want to rebuild a small static-site-generator as microservices.
One microservice to write sourcefiles to the server and another microservice to render pages from these sourcefiles. 
These microservices are only protected by a simple basic or digest access authentication.

After writing the sourcefiles, I have to render pages with the other microservice, but I am not sure how to do authentication.
I thought about these strategies:

- serverbased: call the render-service from writer-service.

  - handing over the users basic auth credential (in PHP with `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`).
  - dedicated system user, used by the writer-service.
- clientbased: call the render-service from users browser (after successful writer-service).

Currently I prefer the clientbased strategy, as there is no authentication hassle on the server. But the integrity between source and rendered files depends on a working browser and net connection.

Comment: It is hard to understand requirements from your sayings but passing the credentials every time you need to call a microservice doesn't sound like a good idea. Maybe you should answer some further questions like "How are you planning to keep the authentication info for the later  microservice calls?" maybe using token.

Comment: @cool you are right with "passing the credentials every time you need to call a microservice" but this comes from [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).


I am not "planning to keep the authentication info for the later microservice calls", basic auth just resends credentials again and again.